# copy duration from one svg animation to another

Tags: animation, svg

I would like to have the same duration on these two SVG animations, but end="showLine.end" does not have any effect.

```
<animate id="showLine" attributeName="cx"  begin="0s"  dur="5s"/> 
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="showLine.begin+0s" end="showLine.end" fill="freeze" from="0,100" to="0,500"/>
```

Please tell me how to copy the duration of one animation to another. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried to set the end time for the second animation to the end time of the first animation (please see the above example), but so far I have not been able to make this work.

Comment: I meant - what have you tried so far to "copy the duration from one animation to another"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use javascript to copy the dur attribute from one node to another.

[You won't get interpolation unless you specify a dur attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#TimingAttributes)

*If the animation does not have a ‘dur’ attribute, the simple duration is indefinite. Note that interpolation will not work if the simple duration is indefinite (although this may still be useful for ‘set’ elements). Except for any SVG-specific rules explicitly mentioned in this specification, the normative definition for this attribute is the SMIL Animation specification. In particular, see SMIL Animation: 'dur' attribute ([SMILANIM], section 3.2.1).
8*

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="300">
  <g>
    <rect id="r" width="100" height="100" x="40" y="20" fill="blue">
      <animate duration="aaa" attributeName="fill" begin="0s" dur="20s" fill="freeze" from="red" to="green"/> 
    </rect>
  </g>
  <script>
    var t = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for(var i = 0; i < t.length; ++i)
     {var T = t.item(i);
      if (T instanceof SVGAnimateElement)
       {T.setAttributeNS(null, "dur", "2s");
       }
     }     
  </script>
</svg>
```